Experimental data yields differing values for Principle Axes is it appropriate to average them?
I recently performed an experiment on a cantilever L beam, loaded at its unsupported end. The load was constant (5N) and the beam was rotated through 0 to 180 degrees. The horizontal and vertical displacements of the beam were recorded against the loading angle.
The principle axes in theory should be at angles where horizontal displacement is zero, and vertical displacement is at max/min. 
This is the graph I have currently plotted is it correct to simply average the Vertical and Horizontal axes to get a single value  or is there a better method?

You say "and the beam was rotated through 0 to 180 degrees," but your graph shows displacement versus loading angle! Which one is correct?
Once you have determined which is right:

H= horizontal displacement
V = vertical displacement
$\alpha$ = angle of displacement vector

$$\vec{D}_{length}=\sqrt{H^2+V^2}$$
$$\vec{D}_{\alpha}= arcsin H$$
But if you want to calculate the principal stress at any cross section, X, You need to calculate the bending moment at X, and from that
$\sigma_X=\frac{M_X*y}{I}$
Then we add axial stress, which we have  its deflection from your chrt to $\ \sigma_X$
$$\sigma_t= \frac{M_X*y}{I}+\sigma_{axial}$$
We know $$\sigma_{axial}=E*\epsilon= E\ \frac{\Delta l}{l}$$
From here on we call $\sigma_{total}=\sigma_x$
and shear at X and from there shear flow
$\tau_{xy}=\frac{V_X*Q}{It}$
$$\sigma_1, \sigma_2= \frac{\sigma_x+\sigma_y}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{\sigma_x-\sigma_y}{2})^2 }+ \tau_{xy^2}$$
$$tan(2\theta_P)=\frac{2\tau_{xy}}{\sigma_x-\sigma_y}$$
$$Axis_P=1/2 arctan(2\theta)$$
I try to answer the questions in detail so that it can be used as a refrence.

Ah, I should have been more specific, the beam is loaded a its unsupported end by a hanging mass, so by rotating the beam its loading angle is varied.

@Wimbled, My answer addresses your question when the rotation of the beam is either slow or done at steps. Otherwise, we need to calculate dynamic forces, acceleration, and centripetal forces.
